# adding words to stopwords in wordcloud does not work

Tags: python, numpy, word-cloud

I want to add some stopwords to wordcloud but the resulting image shows the exact words I add to the stopwords. I am doing something wrong? How can I add the word to the stopwords

```
from wordcloud import STOPWORDS as EN_STOPWORDS
from wordcloud import ImageColorGenerator
from stopword_persian import stopword_persian as STOPWORDS
from wordcloud_fa import WordCloudFa


# Add another stopword
STOPWORDS.add('ميساخته')
stopwords = STOPWORDS.union(EN_STOPWORDS)


# Generate a word cloud image

wordcloud = WordCloudFa(
    persian_normalize=True,
    include_numbers=True,
    max_words=300,
    stopwords=stopwords,
    margin=0,
    width=3000,
    height=3000,
    min_font_size=1,
    max_font_size=500,
    random_state=True,
    background_color="black",
    mask=twitter_mask
).generate(text)
```

Comment: first you could check `print(stopwords)`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953788/why-are-stop-words-not-being-excluded-from-the-word-cloud-when-using-pythons-wo) question I think has better answers for the same problem, basically use `collocations=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nltk # Natural Language ToolKit
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords # to get rid of StopWords 

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator # to create a Word Cloud
from PIL import Image # Pillow with WordCloud to image manipulation

text = 'New stop words are bad for this text.'

# Adding the stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('en') 
new_stopwors = ['new', 'stop', 'words']
stop_words.extend(new_stopwords)
stop_words = set(stop_words)

# Getting rid of the stopwords
clean_text = [word for word in text.split() if word not in stop_words]

# Converting the list to string
text = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in clean_text])

# Generating a wordcloud
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color = "black").generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Here is a helpful [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html) If you want to explore more about the interpolations.