# Why are stop words not being excluded from the word cloud when using Python's wordcloud library?

Tags: python, nlp, word-cloud, stop-words

I want to exclude 'The', 'They' and 'My' from being displayed in my word cloud. I'm using the python library 'wordcloud' as below, and updating the STOPWORDS list with these 3 additional stopwords, but the wordcloud is still including them. What do I need to change so that these 3 words are excluded?

[image: screenshot of my code]

The libraries I imported are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I've tried adding elements to the STOPWORDS set at follows but, even though the words are added successfully, the wordcloud still shows the 3 words I added to the STOPWORDS set:

`len(STOPWORDS)`
Outputs: 192

Then I ran:

```
STOPWORDS.add('The')
STOPWORDS.add('They')
STOPWORDS.add('My')
```

Then I ran:

`len(STOPWORDS)`
Outputs: 195

I'm running python version 3.7.3

I know I could amend the text input to remove the 3 words (rather than trying to amend WordCloud's STOPWORDS set) before running the wordcloud but I was wondering if there's a bug with WordCloud or whether I'm not updating/using STOPWORDS correctly?

Comment: Have you tried add the stopwords all in lowercase?

Comment: 'the', 'they' and 'my' in lower case are already in WordCloud's 'STOPWORDS' list. I added 'The', 'They' and 'My' to the list. The words I added are not being excluded from the wordcloud despite now being in the stopwords list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default for a Wordcloud is that `collocations=True`, so frequent phrases of two adjacent words are included in the cloud - and importantly for your issue, with collocations the removal of stopwords is different, so that for example “Thank you” is a valid collocation and may appear in the generated cloud even though “you” is in the default stopwords. Collocations which contain only stopwords *are* removed.

The not unreasonable-sounding rationale for this is that if stopwords were removed before building the list of collocations then e.g. “thank you very much” would provide “thank very” as a collocation, which I definitely wouldn’t want.

So to get your stopwords to work perhaps how you expect, i.e. no stopwords at all appear in the cloud, you could use `collocations=False` like this:

```
my_wordcloud = WordCloud(
    stopwords=my_stopwords,
    background_color='white', 
    collocations=False, 
    max_words=10).generate(all_tweets_as_one_string)
```

UPDATE:

- With collocations False, stopwords are all lowercased for comparison with lowercased text when removing them  - so no need to add 'The' etc.
- With collocations True (the default) while stopwords are lowercased, when looking for all-stopwords collocations to remove them, the source text isn't lower-cased so e.g.g `The` in the text isn't removed while `the` is removed - that's why @Balaji Ambresh's code works, and you'll see that there are no caps in the cloud. This might be a defect in Wordcloud, not sure. However adding e.g. `The` to stopwords won't affects this because stopwords is always lowercased regardless of collocations True/False

This is all visible in the source code :-)

For example with the default `collocations=True` I get:

[image]

And with `collocations=False` I get:
[image]

Code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


text = "The bear sat with the cat. They were good friends. " + \
        "My friend is a bit bear like. He's lovely. The bear, the cat, the dog and me were all sat " + \
        "there enjoying the view. You should have seen it. The view was absolutely lovely. " + \
            "It was such a lovely day. The bear was loving it too."

cloud = WordCloud(collocations=False,
        background_color='white',
        max_words=10).generate(text)
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: See also [this github issue](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/558) for version 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install nltk
```

Don't forget to install stopwords.

```
python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Give this a shot:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

text = "The bear sat with the cat. They were good friends. " + \
        "My friend is a bit bear like. He's lovely. The bear, the cat, the dog and me were all sat " + \
        "there enjoying the view. You should have seen it. The view was absolutely lovely. " + \
            "It was such a lovely day. The bear was loving it too."
cloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords,
        background_color='white',
        max_words=10).generate(text.lower())
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. I added the same 3 words to the NLTK stopwords list and the wordcloud is still displaying them.

Comment: Lowercased the text and used your input. Check it out now.

Comment: I explained in my answer why lowercasing the text does make stopwords disappear from the cloud, but that doesn't seem like a totally desirable solution. Also you don't need nltk stopwords, the wordcloud.STOPWORDS removes the/they/my etc.. Incidentally in your code in the `text` you missed out space " " after "sat" and "lovely."

Comment: Added the space after  sat and lovely.