# Python WordCloud not removing Stopwords

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, word-cloud

I'm trying to build a Wordcloud that automatically pulls the words from a job description and builds a wordcloud.  If you have the stopwords=None, it's supposed to remove the wordcloud's list of known stopwords, but my program isn't.  I believe it may have to do with how I'm pulling the job description with beautiful soup.  I need help either pulling the words differently with beautifulsoup or I'm not using the stopwords correctly.

```py
import requests
# pip install bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# pip install wordcloud
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Goes to a job description
url = "https://career.benteler.jobs/job/Paderborn-Head-of-Finance-&amp;-Controlling-North-America-NW/604307901/?locale=en_US"
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

# Goes through all the words in the beautiful soup text
combinedWords = ''

for words in soup.find_all('span'):
    separatedWords = words.text.split(' ')
    combinedWords += " ".join(separatedWords) + ' '

# creates wordcloud
resumeCloud = WordCloud(stopwords=None, background_color='white', max_words=75, max_font_size=75, random_state=1).generate(combinedWords)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.imshow(resumeCloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are stop words not being excluded from the word cloud when using Python's wordcloud library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953788/why-are-stop-words-not-being-excluded-from-the-word-cloud-when-using-pythons-wo)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953788/why-are-stop-words-not-being-excluded-from-the-word-cloud-when-using-pythons-wo/61988057#61988057

Comment: @barny, the second helped for sure.  Setting the collocations=False worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that all the code is in one block. Try splitting the logic into methods and test each bit individually. The *request* doesn't check for errors (e.g server might be unavailable *but this shouldn't be an issue now*.)

The BeautifulSoup is extracting all span elements on the page. This means it will include the menu / footer. If you want the job description, then you might want to select the span with the class name jobdescription. Afterwards you can call *text* to remove html. I'm not sure if you need to remove other stuff like commas & full stops.

I don't have any experience with Word Cloud. However in the code below its returning something that looks like results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_job_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status() # check for 4xx & 5xx errors
    return response.text

def extract_combined_words(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    job_description = soup.find("span", {"class": "jobdescription"}).text.replace('\n', ' ') # Target span with class jobdescription. text will strip out html.
    print(job_description) # TODO - Check this is the results you expect?
    return job_description

def create_resume_cloud(combinedWords):
    return WordCloud(stopwords=None, background_color='white', max_words=75, max_font_size=75, random_state=1).generate(combinedWords)

def plot_resume_cloud(resumeCloud):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    plt.imshow(resumeCloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

def run(url):
    html = get_job_html(url)
    combinedWords = extract_combined_words(html)
    resumeCloud = create_resume_cloud(combinedWords)
    plt = plot_resume_cloud(resumeCloud)
    return plt # TODO - not sure how the results gets consumed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run("https://career.benteler.jobs/job/Paderborn-Head-of-Finance-&amp;-Controlling-North-America-NW/604307901/?locale=en_US")
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for to clean up the data.  Additionally, someone else gave me the WordCloud solution as well.  Thanks!!!!!